# Second monitor isn't detected after boot screen

Tags: display, multiple-monitors

Recently connected a second monitor in my graphics card using a DisplayPort to VGA converter cable. The second monitor works fine until the Windows boot screen but as soon as Windows boot screen is over, the first monitor keeps working but the second monitor goes into the "No signal" mode.

Comment: What do you see when you press the Windows+P keys simultaneously? There should be an option to switch to "Duplicate" so you see the same on both.

Comment: @Pianoman Nothing happens. Windows doesn't detect the second monitor at all. I have tried the detect option from display settings too.

Comment: What do you see when you right click on your desktop and select Display Settings ?  Are there one or two screens ?

Comment: @Rohit Gupta As I said before, Windows isn't detecting second monitor at all so there is no option for multiple screens.

Comment: Yes, you did say that, but until you explicitly say that you have tried Display Settings, we do not know.

Comment: Windows version?? XP? 11? Vista? etc.